# Mysql - Taking too much time to execute queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization, execution

So first my mysql table are defined like this :

**Orders**(333000+ records)

```
orders_id(PK), 
customerName, 
CompanyName, 
Status, 
shipping_no, 
shipping_module, 
tracking_no, 
orders_status, 
date_purchased..
```

**Order_status**(70 records)

```
orders_status_id(pk),
language_id,
orders_status_name
```

**orders_status_history**(2220000+ records)

```
  `orders_status_history_id` int(11) 
  `orders_id` int(11)
  `orders_status_id` int(5) 
  PRIMARY KEY  (`orders_status_history_id`)
```

**orders_status_history** table contains different status about every orders

```
  `orders_status_id` int(11)
  `orders_status_name` varchar(32)
  PRIMARY KEY (`orders_status_id`,`language_id`)
```

So what i am trying to get is that all three option below described:

1. Orders Must have `shipping_module` pickup_pickup or pickup2_pickup2
2. `orders_status_history.orders_status_id` Must have following status 7, 21, 34, 40
3. But `orders_status_history.orders_status_id` Must NOT have following status 33,53

Explain Problem : 
Suppose there are 10 orders, and they have had the followings statuses at some time in their life:

1. [7, 34, 41,48]
2. [20, 40, 34, 57, 14, 25]
3. [53,7,40,5]
4. [41,25,4]
5. [1,2,3,4]
6. [34,4,33,53,7]
7. [4,21,31,7,8]
8. [78,15,45,40]
9. [53,40,31,21,7]
10. [33,74,54,7,22]

So Orders that i want to extract are 1,2,7,8 because this orders contain 7,31,21 or 40 and not 53, 33

I have tried following queries :

1.)

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders AS o, orders_status_history AS osh
WHERE (
       o.shipping_module LIKE  '%pickup_pickup%'
       OR o.shipping_module LIKE  '%pickup2_pickup2%'
   )
AND o.orders_id = osh.orders_id
AND osh.orders_status_id
IN ( 7, 21, 31, 40 ) AND osh.orders_status_id
NOT IN (33, 53)
```

This query works ok as performance but it get all result (1200 records) but it didn't filter 3 option

2.)

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders AS o, orders_status_history AS osh
WHERE (
       o.shipping_module LIKE  '%pickup_pickup%'
       OR o.shipping_module LIKE  '%pickup2_pickup2%'
   )
AND o.orders_id = osh.orders_id
AND osh.orders_status_id IN (7, 21, 31, 40) 
AND osh.orders_status_id != 33
AND osh.orders_status_id != 53
```

It works also as previous, didnt filter 3rd option

3.)

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders AS o, orders_status_history AS osh
WHERE (
       o.shipping_module LIKE  '%pickup_pickup%'
       OR o.shipping_module LIKE  '%pickup2_pickup2%'
   )
AND o.orders_id = osh.orders_id
AND osh.orders_status_id IN (7, 21, 31, 40) 
AND osh.orders_status_id NOT IN (
                                 SELECT so.orders_id 
                                 FROM orders AS so, orders_status_history AS sosh
                                 WHERE (
                                        so.shipping_module LIKE  '%pickup_pickup%'
                                        OR so.shipping_module LIKE  '%pickup2_pickup2%'
                                        )
                                 AND sosh.orders_status_id != 33
                             )
```

This query took too much time to execute and didn't excute

4.)

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders AS o, orders_status_history AS osh
WHERE (
       o.shipping_module LIKE  '%pickup_pickup%'
       OR o.shipping_module LIKE  '%pickup2_pickup2%'
   )
AND o.orders_id = osh.orders_id
AND osh.orders_status_id = 7
AND osh.orders_status_id = 21
AND osh.orders_status_id = 31
AND osh.orders_status_id = 40
AND osh.orders_status_id != 33
AND osh.orders_status_id != 53
```

This query works as first too queries didn't filter 3rd option

So later i tried it with php

```
$sql = "SELECT o.orders_id, osh.orders_status_history_id
        FROM 
            orders AS o, 
            orders_status_history AS osh
        WHERE ( 
            o.shipping_module LIKE  '%pickup_pickup%'
            OR o.shipping_module LIKE  '%pickup2_pickup2%'
           )
        AND o.orders_id = osh.orders_id
        AND osh.orders_status_id IN (7, 21, 31, 40) 
        AND osh.orders_status_id != 33
        AND osh.orders_status_id != 53";
$sql    = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $row["orders_id"]);
    if(getOrderStatus($row["orders_id"]))
        echo "<br/>".$row["orders_id"];
}

function getOrderStatus($order){
    $sql    = "SELECT orders_status_id FROM orders_status_history WHERE orders_id = ".$order;
    echo "<br/> Sql Query : ".$sql;
     $sql = mysql_query($sql);
     while ($status     = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
       if((int)$status["orders_status_id"] == 33 || (int)$status["orders_status_id"] == 53)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

This code was taking too much time more than 30m. I `set_time_limit(0);`

**Note:** I can use only Mysql_* because our php version is 4.9

Comment: Besides PHP 4.9 being really outdated (you should advise your boss to upgrade), did you ever run `EXPLAIN ...` on your queries? What kind of indices are set for the tables?

Comment: `osh.orders_status_id IN ( 7, 21, 31, 40 ) AND osh.orders_status_id
NOT IN (33, 53)` doesn't make any sense as if something is ( 7, 21, 31, 40) than it's by definition not (33, 53). Other queries presents the same just in a different form. So are you sure you're still getting records with 33, 53 in your resluts ??

Comment: I haven't seen anyone use php 4 in years... it is heavily outdated and totally not secure. Besides that it should not impact queries.. as @paul mentioned use `EXPLAIN` in front of your queries. It should, well, explain what it does and what indexes it uses... it probably is missing some

Comment: Thanks for helping me. We are using oscommerce 2.2 and there are no indices are set :(.  Can you provide me a demo of EXPLAIN  I have never tried and didn't know about it.

Comment: indices you should add... and also oscommerce 2.2 is, well, about 9 years old?

Comment: it might be cheaper to just set up a new store and migrate everything!

Comment: @RenePot I told many time my boss to upgrade he tolds always everytime we going to do in this year bla bla but didn't.. yes oscommerce 2.2 is almost 9 years old.

Comment: if i add now indices can happen something bad ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150928/discussion-between-hijckboy-and-rene-pot).

Comment: Adding indexes might not help much, because it looks like you're wanting to pull nearly every record out of each table anyway. You wrote: "orders_status_history.orders_status_id Must have following status 7, 21, 34, 40
But orders_status_history.orders_status_id Must have following status 33,53" - copy paste error? these say the same thing

Comment: Need mroe info on what you're trying to achieve with these order statuses. Let us supposed there are 3 orders, and they have had the followings statuses at some time in their life: [7, 33], [7, 40], [53]. Do you mean to say you only want the second one (7/40) because even though the first order has been in 7 (which you  want) it has also been in 33(which you dont want). And of course you don't want the third either because it has only been status 53

Comment: oops sorry yes you are right. i updated question

Comment: When you're working with a boss who insists on using obsolete, slow, and insecure software, there's always the ads in the right-hand column of Stack Overflow. Just sayin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method to get the *orders* that meet your criteria:

```
SELECT o.orders_id
FROM orders o JOIN
     orders_status_history osh
     ON o.orders_id = osh.orders_id
WHERE (o.shipping_module LIKE  '%pickup_pickup%' OR
       o.shipping_module LIKE  '%pickup2_pickup2%'
      ) AND
      osh.orders_status_id IN (7, 21, 31, 40, 33, 53)
GROUP BY o.orders_id
HAVING SUM( osh.orders_status_id IN (33, 53) ) = 0;
```

The `WHERE` selects only the statuses that you care about.  The `HAVING` makes sure you don't have the last two.

If you want the details of the orders or order lines, then you need to join those tables back in.